# Not receiving all user credentials that I'm supposed to recieve

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm building an app with next.js and for auth I'm using next auth, everything is working well, my login backend controller returns user id, name and token once the user is logged.

This is how I configurated my nexthauth file:

```
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
        type: "credentials",
        credentials: {
          email: { placeholder: "Email", type: "email" },
          password: { placeholder: "Password", type: "password" }
        },
        async authorize(credentials, req) {
          try {
            
            const { email, password } = credentials;
            console.log(email, password);
            const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login', 
            {
              method: "POST",
              body: JSON.stringify({
                email,
                password
              }),
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              }
            }
            );
            const user = await res.json();
            console.log(user);
            
            // THE ONLY PROBLEM LEFT IS THAT IM JUS GETTING THE NAME OF THE USER.....
            
            if( user.ok ) return user; else return null;
          } catch (error) {
            throw new error
          }
          }
    })
  ],
//   Session strategy
  // session: {
  //   strategy: "jwt"
  // },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
    // PENDING TO ADD ERROR PAGE
    // error: "/login/error.jsx"
  }
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

As you guys can see there is a console.log(user), and I'm effectively getting right the resp of my backend:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GANb.png)

The problem that I am actually having is that when I use the getSession hook, on the user field I am only getting the name of the user, but I am supposed to receive algo his id and token...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYuAS.png)

I tried to change the structure of my nextauth file based in some docs and videos that I found, but I haven't been able to solve that bug, I'd be so grateful if anyone of you know what I am missing..

This is my login button event:

````
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!loginForm.email || !loginForm.password) {
       return Swal.fire({
        title: 'Error!',
        text: 'Credentials not provided...',
        icon: 'error',
      })
    }
    const user = await signIn("credentials", {
      email: loginForm.email,
      password: loginForm.password,
      redirect: false
    })
    console.log('user: ', user);
    if (!user.ok) {
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Error!',
        text: 'User not found...',
        icon: 'error',
      })
    } else {
      router.push('/home')
    }
  }```
````

Comment: I suspect that from the backend may be your not sending the correct response back. Can you please post your backend API code for this endpoint `http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login`